# Accessibility support in Android custom view with TTS

Tags: android, accessibility, android-custom-view, text-to-speech, android-framelayout

I have an activity of scrollView consists of one **TextView** on top and one **custom view of FrameLayout** with multiple drawable in the bottom. When I first enter the activity, if I first **touch(according to TTS double touch to activate)** on the custom view, TTS is working fine. But if I touch another view like the textView at first after entering the activity TTS in this view working fine also, then if I try to touch the custom view again it is not working accordingly. The focus stays on the textView instead of going to the custom view. So only one time the TTS is working in custom view of this activity if I touch it first after opening the activity. onClick() method of custom View in not invoked this time.
I printed the log by in the below method

```
public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
// method code
}
```

The problem here is TextView focus is not clearing if I touch the custom view after textView. Please help me with this with any solution or suggestion to overcome this problem.
[image]